# google places autocomplet is not showing any resault

Tags: java, android, json, autocomplete, google-places-api

i am trying to build an auto complete from google places
in the debugger i see i get back the result and the JSON parser return a list of the places

but the `autocomplete` list doesn't sown in the app

any suggestion

code is attached below

```
package autocompleat;

import android.R.id;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.hellogooglemaps.MainActivity;
import com.example.hellogooglemaps.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import dialogs.JumpToDialog;

public class Autocomplet extends Activity{
    AutoCompleteTextView atvPlaces;
    PlacesTask placesTask;
    ParserTask parserTask;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.jumpto);
        JumpToDialog jumpTo = new JumpToDialog();   
        jumpTo.getActivity();
    atvPlaces= (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.addressToGo);
    atvPlaces.setThreshold(2);
    atvPlaces.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
         @Override
         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              atvPlaces.showDropDown();
             return false;
         }
        }); 
    atvPlaces.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        placesTask = new PlacesTask();
        placesTask.execute(s.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
}
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... place) {
            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
            String key = "key=AIzaSyC5RuWhqvF4SKLzU3J7edVA07Jqon1qEco";

            String input = "";

            try {
                input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // place type to be searched
            String types = "types=geocode";

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=false";
            String contry= "components=country:isr";

            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = input + "&" + types + "&" + sensor + "&"+ contry+"&" + key;

            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"
                    + output + "?" + parameters;

            try {
                // Fetching the data from we service
                data = downloadUrl(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }
        private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
            String data = "";
            InputStream iStream = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        iStream));

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
            } finally {
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            // Creating ParserTask
            parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Starting Parsing the JSON string returned by Web Service
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;

            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            String[] from = new String[] { "description" };
            int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };

            // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);

            // Setting the adapter
            atvPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
    public void jumpHandler(final View view)
    {
        Intent eintent = new Intent();
        eintent.putExtra("return",R.id.addressToGo);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,eintent);     
        finish(); 
    }

}

package autocompleat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;









import com.example.hellogooglemaps.R;

import android.R.string;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;

/** Customizing AutoCompleteTextView to return Place Description
 * corresponding to the selected item
 */
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /** Returns the place description corresponding to the selected item */
    @Override
    protected CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem) {
        /** Each item in the autocompetetextview suggestion list is a hashmap object */
        HashMap<String, String> hm = (HashMap<String, String>) selectedItem;
        return hm.get("description");

    }
}
```

json parser

```
package autocompleat;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PlaceJSONParser {

/** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
   public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

       JSONArray jPlaces = null;
       try {
           /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
           jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("predictions");
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
        * where each json object represent a place
       */
       return getPlaces(jPlaces);
   }

   private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces){
       int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
       List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
       HashMap<String, String> place = null;

       /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
       for(int i=0; i<placesCount;i++){
           try {
               /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
               place = getPlace((JSONObject)jPlaces.get(i));
               placesList.add(place);

           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }

       return placesList;
   }

   /** Parsing the Place JSON object */
   private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace){

       HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();

       String id="";
       String reference="";
       String description="";

       try {

           description = jPlace.getString("description");
           id = jPlace.getString("id");
           reference = jPlace.getString("reference");

           place.put("description", description);
           place.put("_id",id);
           place.put("reference",reference);

       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return place;
   }
}
```

layout..xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">"

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jumpToTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="קפוץ לכתובת"
        android:textSize="25dp" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/enterAddressTitle"
        android:layout_width="287dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="הכנס כתובת"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <autocompleat.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/addressToGo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/str_atv_places" 
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/jump"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="המשך" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exitJumpTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="צא" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use this method

```
    atvPlaces.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    atvPlaces.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(context,
                            R.layout.adapter_list_item));


                }
            });



private ArrayList<String> autocomplete(String place) {
        ArrayList<String> resultList = null;
        final String LOG_TAG = "Activity_Home";

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            String key = "key=your key";

            // place to be be searched
            String input = "input=" + place.replace(" ", "+");

            // place type to be searched
            String types = "types=geocode";

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=false";

            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = input + "&" + types + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;

            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url_string = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/"
                    + output + "?" + parameters;

            URL url = new URL(url_string);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList<String>(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                        "description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    private class PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
            implements Filterable {
        private ArrayList<String> resultList;

        public PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int index) {
            return resultList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                        // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                        FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }
```

**adapter_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv_123"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_text_size_normal" />
```

Comment: Hope it helps you and please do let me know if you have any queries related to this and if you are satisfied with my answer then please make the question closed by marking it answered.All the best